# why single quotes and double quotes works differently in "bash -c"?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

While using `bash -c` option to spawn new shell before running shell script,
I encountered unexpected action.

When I use `single quotes`, new shell is spawned to run the script.

```
$ bash -c 'echo pid is $$'
pid is 53465
$ bash -c 'echo pid is $$'
pid is 53466
$ bash -c 'echo pid is $$'
pid is 53477
```

But `double quotes` didn't.

```
$ bash -c "echo pid is $$"
pid is 2426
$ bash -c "echo pid is $$"
pid is 2426
$ bash -c "echo pid is $$"
pid is 2426
```

I carefully read [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) and [bash manual](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html) but could not find why.
Anyone knows the reason why?

Comment: Offsite but not offnetwork: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192715/can-someone-explain-exactly-what-is-happening-with-single-quotes-and-double-quot/192724 Not my downvote, btw.

Comment: @JamesBrown Thanks. that is the answer what I'm looking for!

Comment: Say `man bash` and enter `/QUOTING`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when you execute the command

```
$ command "echo pid is $$"
```

The double quotes ensure that the command `command` gets a string passed where all substitutions are done. So assuming that the pid of the interactive shell is 1234. You will get the equivalent

```
$ command "echo pid is 1234"
```

When you use single quotes, the command gets passed the string `echo pid is $$` where `$$` is just like any string. If the command is now `bash`, $$ has a special meaning

```
$ bash -c 'echo pid is $$'
```

So now you get the PID returned of the executed command `bash` and not of your interactive shell.